# What is the fastest way to pass data arrays through the JNI?

Tags: android, c++, performance, java-native-interface

I am developing an Android app using native code for Oboe. I generate data on the c++ side and need to draw that data to a custom View. I also generated data for Oboe from that data.

I could also generate the data on the Java side and pass it to c++, and generate the Oboe data from there. The app is not real time, but I'd like to avoid lag.

I am currently using Set*ArrayRegion() to pass data to Java, but that copies the data. I really only need a reference to the array for read access to the data. Would NewDirectByteBuffer() give me such access? I need to access the data to draw it to the screen and then I can scrap the reference. Will that work or will I need to copy the array? The arrays can be anywhere from under a few thousand elements to over 100 thousand elements. 1000-100,000 elements would probably be average. I am worried about performance.

Would passing data to c++ with Get*ArrayElements() be faster? The doc says it may copy. I could pass the data to c++ and generate the oboe data from it.

Seems like unless I use NewDirectByteBuffer(), I'll end up with two copies of the data. Will that work though, and if not, would Java to c++, or c++ to Java be faster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, measure to see if you can live with the copy (by means of Set*ArrayRegion). It is by far the simplest architecture.

If you cannot, a direct byte buffer shared between Java and C++ would indeed be the optimal solution. Keep in mind that creating a direct byte buffer is potentially expensive, so strive to reuse byte buffers (ie keep a pool around) instead of creating new ones.

Comment: The doc makes it sounds like I need to scrap the reference as soon as possible.

Comment: As long as you make sure there's always a reference to it (eg just keep references in a `static Vector<ByteBuffer>`) and you make sure you're not reading and writing concurrently from both sides, all is fine.

Comment: Never mind, I was thinking of the GetPrimitiveArrayCritical method. That does sound like a bit more work than the Set*ArrayRegion. Thank you for your help!